# Eigenvectors of covariance matrix of residuals are orthogonal to the projection?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthonormal, projection

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{t \times n}$ denote a data matrix. Let $W$ be a $t \times k$ matrix whose columns form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^k$ where $k < n$. Let $R$ be the matrix of residuals such that $R = X - XWW^T$. Let $\Sigma_R$ be the covariance matrix of the residuals with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_n$ and corresponding eigenvectors $v_1, \dots, v_n$. Is there a way to show that $W$ and $v_i$ are orthogonal $\forall \lambda_i > 0$? I.e. $W^T v_i = 0 \quad \forall \lambda_i > 0$?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean when you say that "$W$ is an orthonormal basis". By definition, a basis is a list of vectors, but the object $W$ (which you call a basis) is a matrix. Do you mean to say that *the columns of $W$* form an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: Another strange thing: if $W$ is a matrix whose columns (or rows) form an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb R^n$, then it must hold that $WW^T = I$, which means that $X - XWW^T = 0$. But if this is the case, then it is not clear what you have in mind for the "residuals of $X$"

Comment: @BenGrossmann Sorry, the columns of $W$ form an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^k$ where $k < n$ (edited correction). So $W^TW = I$.